# How to interpret "with _of_ before the thing communicated"?

Tags: definition

I noticed that in business English, "please advise" is often used as a fixed phrase in context where it basically means "please respond". I looked at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advise) and found this among the definitions:

> (transitive) To give information or notice to; to inform or counsel; — **with *of* before the thing communicated.**

Does "*of*" have a special meaning here?

Comment: BTW, I wasn't sure if it belongs to ELL.SE.com or English.SE.com more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word "of" is in italics in the original. The phrase you highlighted, more properly formatted as

- "with *of* before the thing communicated",

means that the word "advise" is accompanied by the word "of", where the word "of" is written "before the thing communicated".

Their example makes this clear:

> We were advised of the risk.

The word "of" accompanies the word "advise(d)", and is written before the phrase "the risk" (which is the thing *communicated* or *advised*).

As @R.M. [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161635/how-to-interpret-with-of-before-the-thing-communicated/161636#comment323720_161636), this is a 'use-mention distinction':

> The distinction between use and mention can be illustrated for the word cheese:
>
> - *Use*: Cheese is derived from milk.
> - *Mention*: 'Cheese' is derived from the Old English word *ċēse*.
>
> The first sentence is a statement about the substance called "cheese"; it *uses* the word 'cheese' to refer to that substance. The second is a statement about the word 'cheese' as a signifier; it *mentions* the word without *using* it to refer to anything other than itself.
>
> [- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)

In the terminology of this distinction, the word "of" in your example is *mentioned* but not *used*.

Comment: See the [use–mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) for more information as to why the italics are important in interpreting the sentence.

Comment: @R.M. Thanks, and spot on - I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Probably worth noting that one wouldn't use *of* in the example in the question. E.g., "Please advise when you're available for a meeting" or "Please advise whether this is possible."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Which example are you referring to? I don’t see one in the question at the moment, but I might have missed something.

Comment: @Lawrence: The first sentence of the question: *"I noticed that in business English, "please advise" is often used as a fixed phrase in context where it basically means "please respond"."* Not a full example by any means, but you wouldn't use "of" there in the context described.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you mean using *of* in conjunction with *please advise*? Some instances are valid - e.g. “Please advise (us) of any dietary requirements.”

Comment: @Lawrence: That isn't in the sense of "please respond," at least not how I read the question's opening. Of course, you *could* say "Please respond with any dietary requirements" but my read was much more along the lines of the examples I gave above. It's not worth an ongoing discussion, though.